# Reduce multiple arrays to a list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to filter and reduce a `List<Map<String, Object>>` to `List<String>` with Java8 new lambdas by doing this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
myObjects.stream()
    .filter(myObject-> myObject.get("some integer value").equals(expectedValue))
    // myObject.get("some attribute") == ["some string", "maybe another string"]
    .map(myObject-> myObject.get("some attribute"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result is a List but I want to combine all the Strings inside the array to the resulting `List<String>`.

To clarify it, this is the result I'm getting now:

```
ArrayList{["some string"], ["another string"]}
```

But I want this:

```
ArrayList{"some string", "another string"}
```

Can someone give me a hint in which part I have to reduce the `String[]` to a `String`? I'd guess its on the `.map()` part but I don't know what I shall change there.

**edit:**

That's how the `List<Map<String, Object>> myObjects` can be generated  for testing purpose:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> myObject = new HashMap<>();
myObject.put("some integer value", 1);
String[] theStringIWant = new String[1];
theStringIWant[0] = "Some important information I want";
myObject.put("some attribute", theStringIWant);
myObjects.add(myObject);
```

Which looks like this:

```
List<MyObject{"some attribute": 1}>
```

*Note*: That's just an example from my unittest. The list normaly contains more than one element and every map has more attributs and not just `some attribute`.

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing your original `Map`, but you probably need `.flatmap(myObject-> ((List) myObject.get("list")).stream())`

Comment: If you give me some minutes I can provide a better example with the actual list. :)

Comment: If I try this I get an `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Comment: Can ``map`` have multiple keys ?

Comment: Yes, my map has multiple nodes.

Comment: I think your final result is not correct as you are overwriting the value associated with the key `some attribute`.
Anyway, so the point is that you have a `List` of `Map`s, where each `Map` contains values of any type and if it happens to be a `String` array you would like to put all its elements into the resulting `List`?

Comment: Then try `flatmap(myObject-> Stream.of(myObject.get("list"))`. However, I do not see how your example map fits your original code. Where is the `"list"` key?

Comment: @user1983983, thanks for the hint, I've corrected my example code. The point is that I know that the value of the key "some attribute" always is an array of strings. The other nodes of the map are irrelevant to me (I just need them for filtering).

Comment: Sure it shouldn't be `myObject->myObject.contains("some attribute")`, or how do you did you do an equals on an String[]?

Comment: @M.leRutte, shame on me. I mixed that up in the example code. The `.filter()` checks for the integer value, now the string array I want to extract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to have another filter, but this is how I'd make it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> myObject1 = new HashMap<>();

    myObject1.put("some attribute", 1);
    myObject1.put("some string", new String[] { "Some important information I want"});
    myObjects.add(myObject1);

    Map<String, Object> myObject2 = new HashMap<>();
    myObject2.put("some attribute", 1);
    myObject2.put("some string", new String[] { "hello", "world" });
    myObjects.add(myObject2);

    Map<String, Object> myObject3 = new HashMap<>();
    myObject3.put("some attribute", 2);
    myObject3.put("some string", new String[] { "don't", "want", "this"});
    myObjects.add(myObject3);

    Map<String, Object> myObject4 = new HashMap<>();
    myObject4.put("some string", new String[] { "this", "one", "does", "not", "have", "some attribute"});
    myObjects.add(myObject4);

    List<String> list = myObjects.stream()
            .filter(map -> map.containsKey("some attribute"))
            .filter(map -> map.get("some attribute").equals(Integer.valueOf(1)))
            .flatMap(map -> Arrays.stream((String[])map.get("some string")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

The result is `[Some important information I want, hello, world]`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to obtain that with the `flatMap` method with returning a `Stream` of the `String[]` instead of the `map` method:

```
myObjects.stream()
    .filter(myObject-> myObject.get("some integer value").equals(expectedValue))
    .flatMap(myObject-> Arrays.stream((String[])map.get("some attribute")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But be aware that if `Arrays.stream((String[])map.get("some attribute"))` throws an `Exception`, e.g. if `map.get("some attribute")` is not a `String[]`, then it would be swallowed by the Stream.

Comment: Sadly your version also gets me `List<String[]>`. The answer from M. le Rutte works for me. But thanks for all the effort you had to put into it (because I made several mistakes in my example code).

Comment: You are right, `Stream.of` just returns a `Stream` with the `String[]` as the single element, which is not what you want. I updated the answer.